# Passing multiple "key-value" pairs as a parameter to a JS function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a date range picker, and I want to pass the two dates (startDate, endDate) to handleFilterChange, which builds an filter object to save in session storage. Currently I try to call the function, giving parameters as two arrays, which obviously doesn't work. Calling the function twice also didn't work.

Is this thing even possible and if, then what would be a correct way to pass these two dates to this function?

handleFilterChange

```
const handleFilterChange = (value, title) => {
    clearPreviousResults();
    const newFilters = {
        ...filters,
        [title]: value,
    };

    saveFilterValue(newFilters, FILTERS_STORAGE_KEY);
    setFilters(newFilters)
```

date picker

```
const handleDateRangeChange = dates => {
    if (!dates || dates.length <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    handleFilterChange( ["startDate", "endDate"], [dates[0], dates[1]] );
    };
```

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways to pass multiple values (array as you have, objects, separated strings etc etc), but it all comes down to how your method _expects_ it to be passed. Which we cant tell from the code youve posted here. We would need to see what `saveFilterValue` and `setFilters` is expecting/doing

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to save an object in the `LocalStorage` or session. I would rather send the whole dates array to `handleFilterChange` function.